# Filtering CSV data using python and storing different values in array

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, python-3.6

I am trying to filter **CSV** file where I need to store prices of different commodities that are > 1000 in different arrays, I can able to get only 1 commodity values perfectly but other commodity array just a duplicate of the 1st commodity.

CSV file looks like below figure:
[image]

**CODE**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# csv file name 
filename = "CommodityPrice.csv"

# List gold price above 1000
gold_price_above_1000 = []
palladiun_price_above_1000 = []
gold_futr_price_above_1000 = []
cocoa_future_price_above_1000 = []

df = pd.read_csv(filename)
commodity = df["Commodity"]
price = df['Price']

for gold_price in price:
    if (gold_price <= 1000):
        break
    else:
        for gold in commodity:
            if ('Gold' == gold):
                gold_price_above_1000.append(gold_price)
                break



for palladiun_price in price:
    if (palladiun_price <= 1000):
        break
    else:
        for palladiun in commodity:
            if ('Palladiun' == palladiun):
                palladiun_price_above_1000.append(palladiun_price)
                break
for gold_futr_price in price:
    if (gold_futr_price <= 1000):
        break
    else:
        for gold_futr in commodity:
            if ('Gold Futr' == gold_futr):
                gold_futr_price_above_1000.append(gold_futr_price)
                break

for cocoa_future_price in price:
    if (cocoa_future_price <= 1000):
        break
    else:
        for cocoa_future in commodity:
            if ('Cocoa Future' == cocoa_future):
                cocoa_future_price_above_1000.append(cocoa_future_price)
                break

print(gold_price_above_1000)
print(palladiun_price_above_1000)
print(gold_futr_price_above_1000)
print(cocoa_future_price_above_1000)

plt.ylim(1000, 3000)
plt.plot(gold_price_above_1000)
plt.plot(palladiun_price_above_1000)
plt.plot(gold_futr_price_above_1000)
plt.plot(cocoa_future_price_above_1000)
plt.title('Commodity Price(>=1000)')
y = np.array(gold_price_above_1000)
plt.ylabel("Price")
plt.show()
print("SUCCESS")
```

Here is my question in detail,

Please use pandas and matplotlib to sort out the data in the csv and output and store the sorted data into the process chart. The output results are shown in the following figures.
Figure 1 The upper picture is to take all the products with Price> = 1000 in csv, mark all their prices in April and May and draw them into a linear graph. When outputting, the year in the date needs to be removed. The label name is marked and displayed. The title names of the chart, x-axis, and y- axis need to be marked. The range of the y-axis falls within 1000 ~ 3000, and the color of the line is not specified.
Figure 1 The picture below is from all the products with Price> = 1000 in csv. Mark their Change% in April and May and draw them into a dotted line graph. The dots need to be in a dot style other than '.' And 'o'. To mark, please mark the line with a line other than a solid line. When outputting, you need to remove the year from the date. You need to mark and display the label name of each line. The title names of the chart, x-axis, and y-axis must be marked. You need to add a grid line, the y-axis range falls from -15 to +15, and the color of the line is not specified.
The upper and lower two pictures in Figure 2 are changed to 1000> Price> = 500. The other conditions are basically the same as in Figure 1, except that the points and lines of the dot and line diagrams below Figure 2 need to use different styles from Figure 1.
The first and second pictures in Figure 1 must be displayed in the same window, as is the picture in Figure 2.

Answer (score 0):

All of your blocks of code are doing the exact same thing. Changing the same of the iterator doesn't change what it does.

```
for gold_price in price:
for palladiun_price in price:
for gold_futr_price in price:
for cocoa_future_price in price:
```

This is going through the exact same data. You haven't subsetted for specific commodities.

Using the break statement in that loop doesn't make sense either. It should be a `pass`.

Basically for every `number` above 1000, you iterate through your entire Commodities column and add `number` to the list for every time you see a specific commodity.

Read how to index and select data in pandas.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

```
gold_price_above_1000 = df[(df.Commodity=='Gold') & (df.Price>1000)]
```